# Is it possible to pass a DataFrame created in Rust to Python?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars, pyo3

I'm looking to create a Rust app with Python plugins using polars. I want to allocate most if not all dataframes in Rust (all the data will be on the Rust side), but then use them in Python in a user defined plugin. Is this possible? I have seen Python --> Rust examples, but not Rust --> Python examples.

Update: `pyo3-polars` does seem to be close to what I need, BUT I think it copies/moves the frame vs. simply wrapping it? I was hoping to have Python simply access the dataframe, not own it.

Comment: Have you seen pyo3-polars? https://github.com/pola-rs/pyo3-polars/blob/0a3df66ce626504e418491cb4b1d31bd3ee7ed6c/example/extend_polars_python_dispatch/extend_polars/src/lib.rs#L13 - you wrap the df/ldf in `PyDataFrame` or `PyLazyFrame` to send it through.

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)